# What types of situations would linear regression outperform randomforest?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, random-forest

I'm working on a data set and linear regression is beating a randomforest (the metric is weighted mean absolute error - I have a list of weights and each difference $|\text{predicted} - \text{actual}|$ is multiplied by that rows weight (which is a $\sqrt{\text{time}}$ so longer time between observations are charged a higher penalty)).

I find this a bit surprising in light of past experience.

I was curious if there are types of data that this would typically happen with AND if there are any types of algo/ml technique that's even better than linear regression.

Comment: How large a data set do you have?  Is your metric calculated on the same data used to fit the model, on a test sample, or using cross-validation?  If the relationship really is close to linear, linear regression is (quite likely) to outperform a random forest...  As for techniques that are better than linear regression, depending on the model and objective function, certainly there are better techniques, e.g., logistic regression for binary outcomes.

Comment: The full data set is roughly 1MM rows X 50 columns, w/ 40 numeric columns and 10 factor columns(each factor has 3 levels).  I have split that into a training set of 200k and a test set of 100k for easier/faster use.

I'm trying to use regression as opposed to classification.